# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, html

I am new to HTML and PHP and currently trying to build my first pages.

I am getting the following error trying to compile the code:

**PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/Z6XJiZ/prog.php on line 45**

Here is the code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo <<< HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>First-Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
HTML;

echo <<< HTML
    <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <img alt="A Cat" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cat-hunting-to-mouse-at-home-burmese-cat-face-before-attack-closeup-picture-id1313021528?s=612x612" class="w-50 h-auto">
    </header>
HTML;

$data = [
    0 => [
        'link' => 'https://www.youtube.com/',
        'text' => 'youtube',
    ],
    1 => [
        'link' => 'https://www.google.com/',
        'text' => 'google',
    ],
    2 => [
      'link' => 'https://www.wikipedia.com/',
      'text' => 'wikipedia',
  ],
];

foreach($data as $item) {
    $link = $item['link'];
    $linkText = $item['text'];
    
    echo <<< HTML
        <a href="$link" target="_blank">$linkText</a>
    HTML;
}

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo '<section>';
    echo '<h2>From-data is available</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>';
    echo '</section>';
}

echo <<< HTML
    <section>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p>Here a form is sent to yourself.</p>
    <form action="live-coding.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <p>
        <label for="myname">Name</label><br>
        <input id="myname" type="text" name="name" value="" required placeholder="enter name">
        </p>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sent">
        </p>
    </form>
    </section>
    <footer class="container">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
        <p><small>Test Page ©</small></p>
    </footer>
HTML;

echo <<< HTML
    </body>
</html>
HTML;
```

Couldn't find any solutions to my problems. Whatever I tried it resulted in more problems/errors...

Comment: I run  the code, no errors.

Comment: The [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) delimiter (`HTML` in your case) had to be on the first column until PHP/7.3. You must be using a very old PHP version.